# How to install dism through command line in windows 7 by booting from a recovery windows 7 iso in a USB?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, crash, windows-update

Recently I installed a faulty security update (2823324) released by Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2839011 . My computer is constantly getting blue screen and restarting. I have tried each and every solution in that kb article.

I tried startup repair without success. I cannnot even boot into safe mode. And I don't have a system restore point.
I tried the same after booting from a win 7 iso loaded onto a usb. I tried startup repair and system restore.
And when I want to try the command line solution listed in that article, I get the error that dism is not found.

I found an article about dism http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825176.aspx in microsoft website. 
It does have a section on , how to copy dism into another computer. But the thing is, I do not know how to copy it using command line when booting from a windows 7 iso in a usb.

Note: I have windows 7 home premium service pack 1 installed in my laptop and in my recovery usb.
Note2: The laptop is a Dell laptop and I had previously deleted the system recovery partition that usually is present in laptops that ships with windows, because I needed to use that space.

Comment: I don't have a Home Premium installation to confirm right now, but I believe dism *is* included with that version. I don't know why you're not able to use it when booting off the ISO.

Comment: i guess this won't help you but I have windows 7 ultimate, and c:\windows\system32\dism.exe is there.  maybe try going to another computer running the windows 2008 resource kit, hope dism is on there     http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343(v=ws.10).aspx  "DISM is available in all installations of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. "  and i guess here  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753     I wonder if copying dism.exe from a usb stick is enough. if you have another windows installation you can get dism.exe no doubt.